# Kafka connect record count mismatch between source and target

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are using kafka connect  JDBC connectors to fetch data from a table in oracle DB using jdbcsource connector and uploading it to target table in postgres DB using jdbc sink connector via a topic.  while performing this activity, we are able to fetch the data from source and update it to target table.  But the count of records in source table  is not matching with the count of records in target DB. Is there a way to check

```
1.  the data fetched by the source connector and uploaded in the topic 
2.  Any way to track the records and identify why its not uploaded in the target table.  
3. How to identify the records that has not been uploaded into the target based on the log details.
```

Comment: You can use jmx metrics https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/monitoring.html

Comment: Do you delete rows from the source table?